# Enabling CORS in laravel using barryvdh/laravel-cors package?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4, cors

I am working on a simple Angular application and I wish to have my back end data from an API I created myself in Laravel. The API is sending back data just fine. But since I am developing my Angular application separately, I have an error when I use a service in Angular to fetch my resource.

**Error**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8001/airports. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

So now I have installed a package in Laravel which is supposed to solve the issue but I am not sure how to use it. The cofig file of the package looks like:

```
'defaults' => array(
        'supportsCredentials' => false,
        'allowedOrigins' => array(),
        'allowedHeaders' => array(),
        'allowedMethods' => array(),
        'exposedHeaders' => array(),
        'maxAge' => 0,
        'hosts' => array(),
    ),

    'paths' => array(
        'api/*' => array(
            'allowedOrigins' => array('*'),
            'allowedHeaders' => array('*'),
            'allowedMethods' => array('*'),
            'maxAge' => 3600,
        ),
        '*' => array(
            'allowedOrigins' => array('*'),
            'allowedHeaders' => array('Content-Type'),
            'allowedMethods' => array('POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE'),
            'maxAge' => 3600,
            'hosts' => array('api.*'),
        ),
    ),
```

I am still getting the same error. Now what is it that I have to different in order to allow CORS?

Note: I have WAMP installed. I am developing both my Angular application and Laravel API on the same local server.

Comment: Are your APIs prefixed with "api/"?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar with EmberJS instead of Angular. Laravel setup looks correct but I think you need to enable CORS support in Angular.

From a Chrome developer tutorial:

> **A word on Content Security Policy**
>
> Unlike many other JS MVC frameworks,
>   Angular **v1.1.0+** requires no tweaks to work within a strict CSP. It
>   just works, out of the box!
>
> However, if you're using an older version of Angular between v1.0.1
>   and v1.1.0, you'll need tell Angular to run in a "content security
>   mode". This is done by including the **ngCsp** directive alongside ngApp:
>
> `<html data-ng-app data-ng-csp>`

You can find the whole article [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/angular_framework).